# Output should be like 19Su20 i.e YearDayMinutes

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have created a table 'Join_Date' with below data:

```
2019-01-27 10:20:15
2019-01-26 10:20:15
```

I am looking for the output should be like:

```
19Su20
```

i.e.

- Year(last two number)
- Day(Two character)
- Minutes(Two number)

Appreciate you help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `DATE_FORMAT` function *almost* is sufficient to generate the output you want.  The problem with `DATE_FORMAT` is that the `%a` format mask is for a three letter, not two letter, abbreviation for the day.  Here is a working solution:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(LEFT(output, 4), RIGHT(output, 2)) AS output
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2019-01-27 10:20:15', '%y%a%i') AS output
    FROM dual
) t;
```

### Demo

Note that the call to `DATE_FORMAT` generates `19Sun20`, and then we use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to remove the third character of the day abbreviation.

Comment: @Tim I suggest that you play around with the demo until it clicks for you.  I have explained what the inner query generates, which is `19Sun20`.  The only other thing you need to do is to use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to remove the `n` from `Sun`.

Comment: Can we create a user define function to get the same output for other dates?